# Available placeholders for {name}, {profile} and {label} in Spring Cloud Config Server?

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I'd like Spring Cloud Config Server to resolve some placeholders at rendering time based on the {name}, {profile} and {label} values passed in the request.

For example I'd like the following `config.txt` plain text file :

```
name=${name}
profile=${profile}
```

to be rendered as :

```
name=my_app_name
profile=my_profile_name
```

when calling `/my_app_name/my_profile_name/config.txt`.

Is it possible ? And in that case what placeholders should I use ? Is there anything to configure in the server to enable this feature ?

Comment: There is an open issue on GitHub https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/410